# Seeing up/down votes of your own posts

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes

When a user reaches 1000 reputation they become an established user. With that comes the ability to see the number of up and down votes on any post. While I have no problem with this privelege being reserved for established users when it comes to other people's posts, I think that a user should be able to see the up/down vote count on their own posts, regardless of their reputation. Is there a reason why they can't? Is the reasoning that, if the post is not CW, they should be able to figure it out using reputation changes?

Comment: There is a feature-request on meta.SO, which is marked as ([meta-tag:status-declined]): [Please enable low-rep users to easily breakout up and down votes on their own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu). One of the answers there mentions a bookmarklet which should enable this feature for low-rep users, too. (I have not tried it.)

Comment: +1 because I did not know about this feature until I read your post.

Comment: I'm going to bring this up internally to see if views have changed. It's still something you should _earn_, but we keep that, as you can only see vote counts on your own posts. Please be patient, it'll be about a week before we meet again for feature stuff.

Comment: This _should_ be discussed Oct 4, 2013 - I'll post an update shortly after.

Comment: @Tim Post an update where?